# why mozilla is not supporting $ in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

The error which I getting is $ is not defined in the alert box
I tried jquery multiple versions

I changed the jquery1.9.1 file versions, but I often getting same error

I changed the browsers, except mozilla that is running without error in mozilla after the $, 
not parsing and also throwing error.

Comment: $ is not defined means the jQuery library isn't loading, likely an error in the URL you're using. Show the code you use to load the jQuery please.

Comment: `Fiddle ? Code sample ? Url ?` There is nothing here that could let us guess what's wrong. We only could suppose ...

Comment: this might be due to jQuery version conflict.  try using `$.noConflict`

Comment: The same code is working with chrome and IE but not in Mozilla

Comment: is this working in other browsers?

Comment: Are you getting any errors previous to jQuery? Browsers will stop parsing scripts after errors.

Comment: Yes that is working with other browsers @PraDes

Comment: @user1671639 I used $.noConflict() now I am getting same error

Comment: yes michael @michaelward82

Comment: If you are getting other errors, then you need to find the source of those errors. Once you fix them then I would expect jQuery to start working.

Comment: @michaelward82 upto jquery function that is working fine, after that I getting error $ is no defined.              Except mozilla that jquery function is working fine.In mozilla only I getting error in $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using plug-ins. Try this:

```
(function($){

    [put your code here]

})(jQuery);
```

That should pass `$` as an alias for `jQuery` into that function, hence `$` will be defined in the scope of that function.